# XSLT: delete duplicates + set sequence

Tags: xslt, duplicates, sequence

I need to delete duplicates from xml + set correct sequence i.e. 10, 20, 30 etc.

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<serviceInvocationRequests>
  <serviceInvocationRequest>
    <requests>
      <workCenter>04901</workCenter>
      <description>Some random description</description>
    <resourceMemberList>
        <resource>R4902A01</resource>
        <sequence>10</sequence>
      </resourceMemberList>
            <resourceMemberList>
        <resource>R4902A02</resource>
        <sequence>10</sequence>
      </resourceMemberList>
            <resourceMemberList>
        <resource>R4902A01</resource>
        <sequence>10</sequence>
      </resourceMemberList>
            <resourceMemberList>
        <resource>R4902A02</resource>
        <sequence>10</sequence>
      </resourceMemberList>
        </requests>
  </serviceInvocationRequest>
</serviceInvocationRequests>
```

My xslt for deleting duplicates:
(currently works on 1 value (common:resource) but probably I will need more - thats why concat added)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key match="resourceMemberList" name="group-key" use="concat(resource, '|')"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="resourceMemberList[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-key', concat(resource, '|'))[1])]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="resourceMemberList"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Remove duplicates works fine, but I need to set sequence to 10 and 20

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serviceInvocationRequests>
   <serviceInvocationRequest>
      <requests>
         <workCenter>04901</workCenter>
         <description>Some random description</description>
         <resourceMemberList>
            <resource>R4902A01</resource>
            <sequence>10</sequence>
         </resourceMemberList>
         <resourceMemberList>
            <resource>R4902A02</resource>
            <sequence>10</sequence>
         </resourceMemberList>
      </requests>
   </serviceInvocationRequest>
</serviceInvocationRequests>
```

How can I achive that?
When I try to add something to xslt duplicate logic gets broken.
Thank you!

Comment: You might need two separate XSLT, one for the duplicates and the other for sorting, then chain the processing. The order may not be important. This would get the job done and doing it might afterwards reveal some way to combine the two solutions into a single XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `xsl:number`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:key match="resourceMemberList" name="group-key" use="concat(resource, '|')"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="sequence">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="pos">
        <xsl:number count="resourceMemberList[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-key', concat(resource, '|'))[1])]"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="10 * $pos"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="resourceMemberList[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('group-key', concat(resource, '|'))[1]))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid having to evaluate the Muenchian expression twice, and do only:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="group-key" match="resourceMemberList" use="resource"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="requests">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="workCenter|description"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="resourceMemberList[generate-id()=generate-id(key('group-key', resource)[1])]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="resource"/>
                <sequence>
                    <xsl:value-of select="position() * 10"/>
                </sequence>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that I have reduced your key from `concat(resource, '|')` to just `resource`. I don't see why you would ever need to add the `|` character to it.